# Adding an Image to Parse Using Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I've searched for a long time now and nothing works out for me. I was able to upload user's username, email, password and a sample location to my "User" class on Parse. But I need to upload an image to Parse for user's placeholder profile image. I have the image in my Assets in Xcode (ProfileImagePlaceHolder.png)

How can I upload this image to Parse as User's Profile picture?

```
 @IBAction func registerTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
    print("Register Page - Register Tapped")

    if txtEmailAddress.text == "" || txtPassword.text == "" || txtPasswordConfirmation.text == ""

    {
        print("Registration fields are not complete.")

        REGISTER_INCOMPLETE_FIELD.show()

    }
    else if txtPassword.text != txtPasswordConfirmation.text
    {

        print("Password Confirmation does not match with Password.")

        PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION_DOESNT_MATCH.show()

    }
    else
    {
        let user = PFUser()

        user.username = txtEmailAddress.text
        user.password = txtPassword.text
        user.email = txtEmailAddress.text
        user["location"] = PFGeoPoint(latitude: 41, longitude: 29)
        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {

                print("There is a problem.")

                SOMETHING_IS_WRONG.show()

            } else {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.

                print("Successfully registered.")

                SUCCESS_REGISTER.show()

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_REGISTERED, sender: self)

                //
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check my below answer?

Answer (score 1):

Parse has an iOS tutorial on this exact topic: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files

Here is the code to save the file to Parse. You can associate this with your PFObject.

```
// Convert to JPEG with 50% quality
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.5f);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:data];

// Save the image to Parse

[imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The image has now been uploaded to Parse. Associate it with a new object 
        PFObject* newPhotoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"PhotoObject"];
        [newPhotoObject setObject:imageFile forKey:@"image"];
        [newPhotoObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Saved");
            }
            else{
                // Error
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

**Here in Swift**

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData)

var userPhoto = PFObject(className:"UserPhoto")
userPhoto["imageName"] = "My trip to Hawaii!"
userPhoto["imageFile"] = imageFile
userPhoto.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: I can't configure this code to my app. When I write,

let imageFile = PFFile(name:"profileplaceholder.png", data:imageData)

it says that "Use of unresolved identifier 'imageData" and if I can't configure this, it saves the image as string not as a file.

Comment: Yes I did, but I couldn't find a solution. I downloaded an app called swiftagram and read it's code then I found a solution but thanks for the help.

Comment: @melkaya If your solution is different than mine then post that as answer for this question. It may be helpful to someone who faces same issue. If both are similar then accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with

```
        let imageToBeUploaded = self.imgProfileImage.image
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToBeUploaded!)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name:"profileplaceholder.png", data:imageData!)
        let user = PFUser()

        user.username = txtEmailAddress.text
        user.password = txtPassword.text
        user.email = txtEmailAddress.text
        user["location"] = PFGeoPoint(latitude: 41, longitude: 29)
        user["image"] = imageFile
```